# Gmail is having authentication problems. Some features may not work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gmail, gmail-api

I am writing a Chrome extension that sends voicemails from Gmail Web App with Gmail API.

I keep getting this red message somewhere around the time that I try to authenticate a user.

[image: Gmail is having authentication problems. Some features may not work.]

My questions:

- Why is this happening?
- Can I somehow download Google Javascript Client library in a way that it doesn't create a global `gapi` variable?

PS. I already tried reading the documentation. Also, the extension works fine, and Gmail works fine, the red message is the only problem.

Comment: Have you considered that this may be a transient problem? For how long have you been getting that?

Comment: @Xan, the problem has been around for a few weeks. It appears only when the extension is running.

Comment: Well then, I'm afraid this question might be in the "can't tell without seeing your code" category.

Comment: See [a related discussion](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/GJzzDRn-qbk), try the suggestion to inspect network traffic.

Comment: if you added the flag("--disable-web-security") to the Chrome shorcut will show this message.

removfe --disable-web-security flag from the Chrome launcher icon

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For the people who are directed here via google search (which I used to), check your extensions. After I research so many hours, I see that one of my extensions is modifying my header, disabling it resolved the problem.

Comment: Yes, this was an issue with a chrome extension I was developing.

Answer (score 6):

Mine was due to `--disable-web-security` flag.

Answer (score 2):

Mine it was because I use header changer plugin in chrome.
Just disable the plugin and everything goes well.

[image: header plugin crhome]

Answer (score 1):

I Don't know if this gonna help you, but I am getting the same error when I enabled this Option at Safari:
**Developer -> Disable Cross-Origin Restrictions.**

I re-enabled it, clicked at login link and the problem has gone away.

[image: See this pic]

Answer (score 0):

You could try the sledgehammer approach and just ignore it....

I've found you can hide the gmail alert and everything still works!

```
//requires jquery    
  setInterval(function(){

    var gmalert = $('div[class="UC cd"][aria-live="assertive"][aria-atomic="true"][role="alert"]')[0];
    if(gmalert){
          gmalert.children[0].children[1].style.display = 'none';
          console.log('gmalert='+gmalert.children[0].children[1].innerHTML);
        }

  }, 15000);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is usually due to extensions that modify headers.I had an extension that modified the token while working on my project to enable me work with the browsable API and once i disabled it everything was ok

Answer (score 0):

Disable your modHeader or any other chrome extensions which are adding extra header 
package or body parameter to the going packets from your side. check your chrome extension, Its only because of extra parameter in your going packet.

Answer (score 0):

Remove any Extensions editing your headers, check if you've got `ModHeader` installed and remove it, if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was the confidentiality mode in the DuckDuck Go add-on in Firefox...

Answer (score 0):

I was passing an Authorization header in Mod Header. Disabled it and the error went.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all Cookies for this site, this fixed this case.